# BASH - How to retrieve rows from a file from #SOF to #EOF

Tags: bash

How to retrieve rows from a file from #SOF to #EOF

```
in source.sh
#SOF
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
"Vivamus pretium enim"
"Est accumsan enim magnis"
#EOF

#SOF
"Eleifend tincidunt id justo"
"Tellus ut tincidunt vel ac a orci"
"Sapien Nullam Sed nunc"
"Vestibulum est accumsan enim"
#EOF

#SOF
"Consequat mauris mollis montes"
#EOF
```

I need to get 3 files

```
in target_1.sh
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
"Vivamus pretium enim"
"Est accumsan enim magnis"

in target_2.sh
"Eleifend tincidunt id justo"
"Tellus ut tincidunt vel ac a orci"
"Sapien Nullam Sed nunc"
"Vestibulum est accumsan enim"

in target_3.sh
"Consequat mauris mollis montes"
```

Tell someone how to do it? thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '/^#EOF$/ {do_print=0}
     do_print {print > ("target_"f_index".sh")}
     /^#SOF$/ {do_print=1; f_index++}' source.sh
```

**Input / Output:**

- Matches example shown in question.

**Explanation:**

- `awk '...'`: Invoke awk, a tool for manipulating text files line by line. The instructions enclosed by the set of single quotes are given to awk.
- `/^#EOF$/ {do_print=0}`: The `^` is regex anchor for "start of line", and `$` is anchor for "end of line". Here we are saying, if we see `#EOF` as the only thing on a line, turn off the printing flag `do_print`.
- `do_print {print > ("target_"f_index".sh")}`: This is run for every line parsed by awk. If the `do_print` flag is set, then append the line to an output file with an index specified by `f_index`.
- `/^#SOF$/ {do_print=1; f_index++}`: Likewise, if we see only `#SOF` on a line, turn on the printing flag, and increment the `f_index` by one.
- Note that it's these last 3 things are evaluated for EACH line, that's why we look for EOF first, then print the line if applicable, then look for the SOF afterwards - we don't want to print `#EOF` or `#SOF`.
- `source.sh`: specify the name of the input file to `awk`; save a cat.

Comment: I already upvoted this answer. I like the edited version even better.

Comment: @glennjackman You guys are teaching me a lot of new things on SO; I'm slowly picking them up a little bit at a time ;)

Answer (score 4):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) will do it gracefully :

```
awk '
    /^#EOF/{l=0}
    l {
        print > "target_" file ".sh"
    }
    /^#SOF/{l=1;file++}
' source.sh
```

**AFTER PROCESSING**

```
$ ls -1t target_*
target_1.sh
target_2.sh
targer_3.sh
```

**EXPLANATION**

- `l {}` is the same as `if (l==1) {}` because `1` is a *true expression* for `awk`

Comment: You don't need the `&& !/^#SOF/` part if you put `/^#SOF/` *after* the print block.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (your only one tag), try doing this :

```
#!/bin/bash
c=0
while read a; do
    if [[ $a =~ ^#SOF ]]; then
        l=1
        ((file++))
    fi

    [[ $a =~ ^#EOF ]] && l=0

    if [[ ! $a =~ ^#SOF ]] && ((l==1)); then
        echo $a >> "target_${file}.sh"
    fi
done < input_file
```